# Embed an image stored from the FileSystemStorage to the WebBrowser component in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How can I embed an image if I stored an image in a FileSystemStorage?
I would like to have the embedded image appended within an element in a WebBrowser component (say inside a DIV)

Do I need to use an OutputStreamWriter? or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic across platforms since every platform treats the base URL differently.

The workaround is to replace the image with data URI which is very portable. So instead of doing this:

```
String htmlText = "... <img src=\"" + fileURL +"\" /> ";
```

Do this:

```
String htmlText = "... <img src=\"" + WebBrowser.createDataURI(imageByteArrayData, "image/png") + "\" /> ";
```

Which will effectively embed the image directly into the HTML/CSS code.